# I want to make overall scrollview in React native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, flatlist

I'm making a app in react native cli.
I have a question.
I want to make scrollable screen but I heard it is impossible.
I'm using flatlist in stack navigator.
But I heard about that is imopssible to using flatlist and scrollview together.
But I want to make this screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMkN2.png)

Here is a picture that I want to make.

Please let me know how to make this screen. :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnY1d.png)
I want to make this screen.

I tried headerlist and footer list in flat list.
But upper area have to be fixed.
And the Top tab navigator can't be contained flat list I think.

Please help me ...

Comment: If my answer is working for you then do upvote so SC can better reach this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scrollview and apply the nestedScroll to true.
In the both flatlist & scrollview give the nestedScroll props to true.

If anything let me know.

```
nestedScrollEnabled={true}
```